# My foreach loop only print one value from Json result

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array, foreach

I want to print this Json result as a list in PHP.
But I only receive one result.
How do I do if I want to echo all items in list.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `var_dump()` the `json_decode()` result. If it's empty get the `json_last_error_msg()`.

Answer (score 0):

You only have one element in $wizards, so it'll only output one.

change your foreach statemet to below,

```
foreach ($wizards[0] as $wizard) {

    echo isset($wizard[0]['streetAddress']) ? "".$wizard[0]['streetAddress']."" : '';

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is fine, but the JSON you provided is invalid.

On the third line from the end, there shouldn't be a comma :

```
        ],
  }
]
```

Should be :

```
        ]
  }
]
```

And you have a duplicate "houses" entry starting form line 635.